# How to embed streaming Video (rtmp) in HTML

Tags: html

How to embed streaming Video (rtmp) in HTML
link rtmp : http://42.116.119.44:4022/udp/225.1.2.244:30120

Comment: Please, view this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. There you can find description on how to write good questions. Please, describe what have you tried, and which results did it get to you. Are you absolutely sure that `html` is the only tag which you need? Maybe you need `rtmp` too?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of player. One example is http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html

See also: [free video player for RTMP & support ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748501/free-video-player-for-rtmp-support-ads)